# Border on three sides

Tags: wpf, border

Is there way to create a border that is only on the top, left, and right sides?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Yes:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1 1 1 0" BorderBrush="Black"/>
```

Same as goes for Margin, Padding etc.

Comment: Shouldn't it be BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" ?

Comment: @Vivek: Just a matter of preference - I hate the commas :-)

Comment: +1 did not know that... also did not know you could set different border thickness.

Answer (score 19):

And just for fun, to do so in code:

```
var b = new Border(); 
b.BorderThickness = new Thickness{Top=1, Bottom=0, Left=1, Right=1};
```